# How to reintroduce weekend days into a date difference that is currently calculated on weekdays?

Tags: excel, date

This question to my knowledge isn't a duplicate - I've looked around and haven't found this exact question. So my question is this: using today's date and a number of days (that's currently a measure of weekdays to an origin date) I want to find the number of total days (including weekend days) that are between today and that previous date. I'm assuming M-F are weekdays and Sa-Su are weekend days. Essentially I want to add back in those weekend days as I count backward towards the origin date so I can figure out what the true origin date is. For example:

```
Origin Date    # Weekdays    Today's Date
    ??              5          8/7/2015
    ??              20         8/7/2015
    ??              100        8/7/2015
    etc...
```

This will need to be a dynamic solution since **Today's Date** will change. 
Also the answer needs to be in Excel because my client only uses/understands Excel.

I don't want an approximate solution (e.g. `# Weekdays * 7/5`) but I do understand the lack of an exact answer in instances where the origin date occurs on a weekend. In these cases, I'm willing to round to Monday. I realize this may beyond the powers of Excel but interested to see if any of you have a solution.

Comment: Is `=WORKDAY(C2, -B2)` not getting the correct results?

Comment: @Jeeped, didn't realize `=WORKDAY()` was out there, thanks! It looks like it rounds towards Monday instead of towards the preceeding Friday for Origin dates that fall on the weekend - do you by chance know how to make it round the other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The native [WORKDAY function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/WORKDAY-function-F764A5B7-05FC-4494-9486-60D494EFBF33) or [WORKDAY.INTL function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/WORKDAY-INTL-function-A378391C-9BA7-4678-8A39-39611A9BF81D) can count backwards just as easily as forwards.

[image: Count WORKDAY backwards]

The formula in A2 is,

```
=WORKDAY(C2, -B2)
```

I've used the older WORKDAY but there are expanded weekend options with WORKDAY.INTL (click on links above for documentation).

Comment: @rmbaughman  -It isn't actually rounding toward Monday since Saturday and Sunday are never considered in the equation. `8/7/2015` minus 4 workdays is a Monday and `8/7/2015` minus 5 workdays is a Friday. Sat and Sun are not considered as they are not workdays. I'm sure some sort of rounding would be possible but you would have to redefine what 'rounds up to Monday'.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Appreciate the help!